# Confused about when mysql code is injection proof using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I understand the basic idea of how mysql statements can be vulnerable, but every time I try to find a useful guide, the ways to achieve this with PDO looks different from eachother. Also, I´m sometimes being told here at stackoverflow that my code is vulnerable such as the other day where it was said about the following (which doesn´t work btw, but I was taught how to make it so:

```
$search = $_GET["search"];
$searcharray = explode('|', $search);
$query=("SELECT username,sender,message,subject,timestamp,threadid,msgtype 

FROM Messages WHERE  ('" . implode("'|'",$searcharray) . "') IN CONCAT 
(message,subject)  ORDER BY timestamp");
```

.. but why? Would it not be enough to have:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

before the code and

```
$result = $conn->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

afterwards?

Are people automatically assuming that I don´t have these parts because I only  post the part which is relevant for my question, or is there a part of my SELECT statement that in itself is vulnerable?
Also, do I need to PDO-ify all mysql statement, so not only SELECT but also UPDATE, INSERT etc. needs to be updated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not enough to simply build strings and send them to PDO, most of the protection granted comes from using prepared statements with bound variables -- [this popular q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/4096667) has some good info for you.

Comment: Thanks A C, I´ll check it out!

Comment: If I provided your page with `?search=');%20DROP%20TABLE%20Messages;%20--`, your script would happily send that to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is vulnerable because you directly use input send to the server without escaping it (e.g. $_GET)
You should use **prepared statements** and **bind** the variables you're using:

```
$search = $_GET["search"];
$searcharray = explode('|', $search);
$query=("SELECT username,sender,message,subject,timestamp,threadid,msgtype 

FROM Messages WHERE  :searchParams IN CONCAT 
(message,subject)  ORDER BY timestamp");

$query = $conn->prepare($query);
$query->execute(['searchParams' => implode("'|'",$searcharray)]);
```

This way, the user input gets escaped.

Comment: Thanks, but should it really be "WHERE :searchParams"? searchParams is not defined before that.

Comment: that doesn't matter, :searchParams is just a placeholder, it gets replaced when you execute the query.